# Mortgage loan calculator

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I need some help creating a mortgage loan calculator that  allows the user to input the loan amount, loan years and loan rate and calculates the monthly mortgage payment and displays the amounts due for each month in a datagridview control.  The problem is , i cannot seem to loop it using a for loop, i need to use the loop to display all the monthly payments but with my attempt it just repeats the same amounts for every month.Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim loanAmount As Double
    Dim loanYears As Integer
    Dim loanRate As Double
    Dim monthlyPayment As Double
    Dim numberofPayments As Integer
    Dim monthlyInterest As Double
    Dim decimalInterest As Double
    Dim interestPaid As Double
    Dim newBalance As Double
    Dim principle As Double
    Dim n As Integer

    Dim Pmt As Integer = 1


    loanAmount = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    loanYears = Val(TextBox2.Text)
    loanRate = Val(TextBox3.Text)

    decimalInterest = loanRate / 100
    numberofPayments = loanYears * 12
    monthlyInterest = decimalInterest / 12

    Label1.Text = monthlyPayment

    For Pmt = 1 To numberofPayments
        n = n + 1
        If n = numberofPayments + 1 Then
            Exit For
        End If
        monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterest / (1 - (1 + monthlyInterest) ^ -numberofPayments)
        interestPaid = loanAmount * monthlyInterest
        principle = monthlyPayment - interestPaid
        newBalance = loanAmount - principle
        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(n, Math.Round(monthlyPayment, 2), Math.Round(interestPaid, 2), Math.Round(principle, 2), Math.Round(newBalance, 2))
    Next
End Sub
```

If someone could please help me out , it would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You do know VS includes a powerful step-debugger, right?

Comment: One note - the "n" variable is unnecessary. The loop will proceed properly without it. Also, deduct the amount from each iteration from loanamount until 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need `loanAmount = loanAmount - principle` inside the `For`, or some other statement that tracks the principle balance and uses it in each iteration. It looks like you're trying to do that with the newBalance variable, but each iteration status over with loanAmount, which never decreases, so the values never change. I would suggest tracing through your math and making sure that your algorithm is actually performing the operations you desire.